# Google Analytics Referral Filter

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to exclude referral traffic within Google Analytics from certain domains using a single regex.

````
I want to exclude traffic from.

team.abc.com
team.example.com
team.xyz.com
team.rfr.com


```and many more.
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `team\.(abc|example|xyz|rfr)\.com`

tested here: https://regex101.com/r/70tyKb/1

Updated here, for a more general pattern: `team\.((\w|-){1,20})\.com`
https://regex101.com/r/7qguHq/1

I assume the length of the mid part is from 1 to 20. Feel free to update.

Comment: I have more than 1000 such domains.

team.abc.com
team.example.com
team.xyz.com
team.rfr.com
team.1.com
team.2.com
team.3.com
team.4.com
team.5.com
team.6.com and so on till team.1000.com

How to proceed in that case?

Comment: Makes sense. Added another regex to make it more vague.